# copy paste from window to reflection xterm

Tags: terminal

I'm using reflection x-window to connect to a linux server.
I have problem with copy+paste from my computer (windows xp) to the 
reflection xterm. it does not work.
The other way around works: from xterm to windows.

any one know how to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: Reflection isn't the same as xterm.

Answer (score 0):

Try pasting into xterm with `Ctrl+Shift+v` instead of `Ctrl+v` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the middle scroll button on your mouse.